# What does the superscript $t$ in this matrix addition problem mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know matrix addition is pretty easy - for a problem like $$\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}$$ The solution is $$\begin{bmatrix} a+e&b+f\\c+g&d+h\end{bmatrix}$$
However, I am working through some problems in [this pdf](http://linear.ups.edu/version3/pdf/fcla-draft-solutions.pdf) and I can't seem to figure out what is meant by the following problem (pg 51, problem C10 part 3):

> Let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 3&2&1\\-2&-6&5\end{bmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{bmatrix}2&4\\4&0\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Find $B^t + C$.

My first thought was, oh, they're not the same shapes, so I can't add them. But it gives a solution. So what does the superscript $t$ mean?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is the matrix's transpose. Google it. It means rows become columns and the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, $t$ refers to the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of a matrix.  In particular, you should find that
$$
B^t = \pmatrix{3&-2\\2&-6\\1&5}
$$

Comment: Ah, thank you, this makes sense. So, then, the top row becomes the first column. Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means the matrix transpose.

In other words, just take the rows of the matrix, and make them as columns.

**Example**

In your case you have

$$
B^T = \pmatrix{3&-2\\2&-6\\1&5}
$$